# The Solidity version pragma statement in these files doesn't match any of the configured compilers in your config. hardhat-deployment

Tags: contract-development, hardhat-deploy, compilation, version-pragma

in trying to compile a contract i keep getting this error:
The Solidity version pragma statement in these files doesn't match any of the configured compilers in your config. Change the pragma or configure additional compiler versions in your hardhat config.

- @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol (^0.8.20)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/IERC721Metadata.sol (^0.8.20)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol (^0.8.20)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/introspection/IERC165.sol (^0.8.20)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/introspection/ERC165.sol (^0.8.20)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/interfaces/draft-IERC6093.sol (^0.8.20)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721Receiver.sol (^0.8.20)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol (^0.8.20)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SignedMath.sol (^0.8.20)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/Math.sol (^0.8.20)
- @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Context.sol (^0.8.20)

These files and its dependencies cannot be compiled with your config. This can happen because they have incompatible Solidity pragmas, or don't match any of your configured Solidity compilers.

---

`````
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

// Import the openzeppelin contracts 
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

// NFTee is ERC721 signifies that the contract we are creating imports ERC721 and follows ERC721 contract from openzeppelin

contract NFTee is ERC721 {
    constructor() ERC721("NFTee", "ITM") {
        // mint the NFT to yourself
        _mint(msg.sender, 1);
    }
}````

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
i have already tried modifying my pragma statement to "^0.8.20" but this causes other issues to arise in my code. any help is highly appreciated.
`````

Comment: what's the version in your hardhat.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in you hardhat.config,js file:

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.20",
    },
}
```

This will tell hardhat what version to use for compiling.

Comment: thank you so much!